# SQL timestamp +1 hour?

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason my SQL database records data an hour before. If I enter data at 22:00 it will show as 21:00.

Is there a way I can +1 hour automatically? Thanks.

Comment: Please try this, `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_york');`, change to the location you need.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the correct timezone for the database:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: How would I do this if I am not running a server though? I am using my hosting provider.

Comment: @Jessiikah1992 It depends whether you're using something like PHP or not. You can set your app to do all the formatting for you. The question was tagged as PHP, but the best way to go about it (if you can) is to set it in MySQL's configuration.

Comment: I am using PHP on my site but where would I add the code?

Comment: @Jessiikah1992 You'd have to make sure that every page that is run by PHP had it running before any calls to the MySQL database. For example, in CodeIgniter I would put it in the site's index.php file at the very top.